# installing snow leopard from tiger. will i lose programs files?

Tags: mac

firstly if i upgrade from tiger to snow leopard can i use the $30 disk as  i have read.
secondly, will ilife '07 and other programs still run properly.
finally, is it worth upgrading if im using a first gen macbook core duo with 1.5 ram?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can upgrade to SL from Tiger, no questions asked - though Apple does *recommend* you get the Boxed Set.

iLife '07 will run definitely, in fact most applications will run. However, do check [with Apple](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3258) or this [wiki](http://snowleopard.wikidot.com) to see if your application will run. Just to clarify - SL will **never** delete your applications, if it is on the blacklist, it will just move it to a folder.

Of course it's worth upgrading - even more so because you are on Tiger. ;)